# Unable to upgrade MinGW in Windows 7

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw

The `GCC` version in my Windows 7 machine is `4.6.2` and I wish to upgrade it. However I fail to do so from both the Command Prompt, as well as the GUI version called *MinGW Installation Manager*.

While trying from the Command prompt, I did the following:

1. `mingw-get update` # worked fine and updated the packages
2. `mingw-get upgrade` # threw a popup saying "*mingw-get.exe has stopped working. Windows is checking for a solution to the problem..*"

While trying from the GUI *MinGW Installation Manager*, I did the following:

1. `Menu Bar -> Installation -> Update Catalogue` # worked fine and updated the packages
2. `Menu Bar -> Installation -> Mark All Upgrades` # threw a popup saying "*MinGW Installation Manager has stopped working. Windows is checking for a solution to the problem..*"

I have verified that the installation directory `C:\MinGW\bin` is added as the `PATH` Environment Variable.

Comment: Have you resolved it now?

Comment: Nope, still unresolved.

Comment: I tried reinstall MingW and that helped. Now I can install new packages.

Comment: I have the exactly same problem, will try reinstalling it.